# Write failed to Google Cloud Bucket

Tags: php, linux, google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage, google-compute-engine

I have been trying to perform a simple write to my Google Cloud Bucket using the php sample that Google provides. My problem is that my remote Google Cloud VM Server does not seem to be functioning correctly. I followed all of the instructions on the website except creating a client ID because I have already created 2 so I used one of those. One of the problems I observed while trying to implement this is that php does not seem to including the google cloud storage libraries. I downloaded the git as the website instructed and I even included the path in the php.ini. This is what i included
`include_path = ".:/usr/bin/php:/google-api-php-client/src"`       I find that even after I adding this, when I try to run

```
<?php file_put_contents('gs://myappid.appspot.com/hello.txt', 'Hello');?>
```

I get the error `Unable to find wrapper 'gs//'`. Even adding `require_once(google-api-php-client/autoload.php)` does not fix the problem. After I added require_once... my code does not run past this point. It does not throw an error, it just stops running. I am lost at how to store files into my bucket via php. I follow the instructions on Google strictly but nothing seems to work.

Comment: Just to clarify, are you using App Engine or not? And which sample are you using? Can you include a URL to its code?

Comment: I am using Google Compute Engine and here is the link https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/json-api-php-samples

Answer (score 2):

The gs:// wrapper is only provided on Google App Engine, not Google Compute engine.

Comment: How do I store in a bucket using compute engine then?

Comment: I've never done it from GCE - I'd take a read through the methods avaialble here: https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client/blob/master/src/Google/Service/Storage.php

Comment: What I dont understand is what is the difference? From what I understand the App Engine provides support for web applications and libraries that are like Compute Engine. But when it comes to storing into cloud storage from my server? Why does it matter if I have App Engine or compute Engine? Isnt storing in the bucket a standalone operation?

Comment: App Engine is a PAAS, we supply libraries and services that you can use with your code (like the gs:// wrapper, task queues, memcache etc). Compute Engine is an IAAS, you need to supply the libraries and services you use with your code. If you want memcache, you need to configure it - if you want to write to GCS, you need to get the right library and configure it to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

As long as you have read and write allowed in your google compute engine, gcloud or gsutil should already be installed. Then try using normal gsutil commands like:

```
exec("/usr/bin/gsutil -m cp -R file.png gs://bucket/images/", $output, $image_return);
```

Log into your compute engine and try out like `gsutil ls`